# Extension of Uniformly Differentiable function - from open ball to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $U$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Suppose $f$ is uniformly differentiable on $U$:
>
> $$\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|{\bf h}|\!|<\delta,{\bf x},{\bf x}+{\bf h}\in U \Longrightarrow |\!|f({\bf x}+{\bf h})-f({\bf x})-f'({\bf x})({\bf h})|\!|<\epsilon \|{\bf h}\|$$

That is, the $\delta$ is valid for all ${\bf x}$.

I wonder if the following is true:

> **Question**: Can we always construct an extension of $\bar{f}$ of $f$, such that $\bar{f}({\bf x}) = f({\bf x})$, for ${\bf x} \in U$, and $\bar{f}$ uniformly differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $n=m=1$, $U=(-1,1)$, $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$.
Obviously $f$ is differentiable on $U$, but not at $x=-1$.

In fact, the tangent there would become vertical, or equivalently:
$f'(x)$ would increase beyond any bound.

--- rk

Comment: Your $f$ is differentiable on $U$, but not uniformly differentiable on $U$.